# .bashrc is not executed in pycharm terminal automatically

Tags: bash, linux-mint

I am using Linux mint 20.3 and Pycharm CE 2021.3.2 version.

I am creating critical environment variables in .bashrc. Unfortunately, when starting a pycharm terminal, bashrc is not executed. I am pretty sure of that because I added some echo commands at the beginning and end of the .bashrc.

What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually using bash? Look in settings under Tools->Terminal->Shell path and check. I've never used pycharm but it looks like it has a lot of integration with the shell so it might not load .bashrc. Maybe there is a setting for the shell that can source/load scripts on startup?

Comment: It is using /bin/sh as default for command lines

Comment: I don't know about Mint but in Ubuntu /bin/sh is actually dash, not bash. Try setting /bin/bash.

Comment: Bash man page has an excellent INVOCATION section which will instruct you a to how and when it reads its various init files.

Comment: @CR I used bin/bash as you suggested and now it is running . Thanks! Please consider putting your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: For future reference,  ``echo "$SHELL"`` and ``printf '%s\n' "$0"`` might be more reliable ways of determining what shell is *actually* running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in settings under Tools->Terminal->Shell path and check to make sure it's set to use Bash.

Set to `/bin/bash` if not.